# $sessionStorage (ngStorage) issue in angularjs when published in IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, sessionstorage

I am using sessionStorage in agularjs application. it is working fine in the IIS express. But when I published the web site in IIS, data is not retriving for the first time. If I press CTRL + F5 then the data get displayed for an hour again facing the same issue. can any one help me on this?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage are only browser dependent, you can check the issue with a different version of the same browser.